# How do I specify composite characters like CTRL + E?

Tags: c#, sendkeys

I am echoeing the contents of a text file into a window. I can specify
decipher \b as {BS}, \t as {TAB}, \n as {ENTER} etc.

1. Where do I find a complete list of the C# escape character and its associated typewriter string i.e. \b is the C# escape sequence and {BS} is the typewriter string?
2. I need a list that includes composite typewriter strings like Shift+F1 etc.

Thanks.

Comment: Finding a \b in a text file is like finding white-out on your monitor.

Comment: @Hans: Your comment is irrelevant: C# can write \b to a file & reading that file char at a time, C# finds it.

Answer (score 2):

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx) notes the following:

To specify keys combined with any combination of the SHIFT, CTRL, and ALT keys, precede the key code with one or more of the following codes.

```
Key      Code  
SHIFT    +  
CTRL     ^  
ALT      %
```

Comment: I want to know how to write SHIFT+ in the file that I'll echo to the window. I write \b for {BS}: How Do I write SHIFT + such that C# knows it is a composite character rather than S followed by H followed by I etc. ?

Comment: If you want to send Shift+F1 you type +{F1}